# TypeScript Compiler Message: "error TS2137: Class declares interface but does not implement it"

Tags: typescript

I have this strange behavior with the typescript compiler version 0.9.5 beta:

Given this (stripped-down) code in a library definition file `lib.d.ts`:

```
declare module Test {
    export interface GenericInterface<T> {
        method(t:T):T;
    }

    export interface IFoo {
        generic<T>(): GenericInterface<T>;
    }

    export class Foo implements IFoo {
        generic<T>(): GenericInterface<T>;
    }
}
```

I get this compiler error for the declaration of the `Foo` class:

```
    error TS2137: Class Foo declares interface IFoo but does not implement it:
    Types of property 'generic' of types 'Foo' and 'IFoo' are incompatible:
        Call signatures of types '<T>() => GenericInterface<T>' and '<T>() => GenericInterface<T>' are incompatible:
            Types of property 'method' of types 'GenericInterface<{}>' and 'GenericInterface<T>' are incompatible:
                Call signatures of types '(t: {}) => {}' and '(t: T) => T' are incompatible.
```

Interestingly if `method` does not have a generic return value, the compiler is happy. Also if the type `T` exists in the parameter list of `generic`, the problem is gone.
I am aware that this is a very special use-case (the type parameter only influences the return type; in my case, I do have another parameter, that implicitly has that information), but right now this is how my existing library looks like.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the compiler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely a compiler bug - this works in 0.9.1.1.

Comment: Thanks! Should I file a bug or did you?